# Determine all connected graphs $G$ of order $n \geq 4$ such that $G \vee K_1$ is outer planar

Tags: graph-theory

Determine all connected graphs $G$ of order $n \geq 4$ such that $G \vee K_1$ is outer planar.

My professor say the answer is $G=P_n$, but he didn't tell us why.

I know that $H$ is outer planar if and only if $H \vee K_1$ is planar, that mean $H$ doesn't contain any subdivision of $K_4$ or $K_{2,3}$.

So in order for $G \vee K_1$ be outer planar, $G \vee K_1 \vee K_1$ must be planar. However, this can't help me to see why $G$ must be a path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about looking at $G \vee K_1 \vee K_1$...

But suppose $G$ is not a path.

Suppose first that $G$ has a vertex $u$ of degree 3 or more, and call its neighbors $x,y,z$.
In $G \vee K_1$, denote by $w$ the vertex of $K_1$.  Then, $\{u, w\} \cup \{x,y,z\}$ form a subgraph isomorphic to $K_{2,3}$ (by dropping the appropriate edges).

If $G$ has no vertex of degree 3 or more and is not a path, then it must be a cycle since it's connected.  Let this cycle be $v_1v_2 \ldots v_nv_1$.  This is actually a subdivision of $K_3$ (just contract the $v_3 \ldots v_n$ vertices), and thus $G \vee K_1$ is a subdivision of $K_4$.

Comment: Also, you have that $G \lor K_1 \lor K_1 \cong G \lor K_2$. So, by the same arguments presented by Manuel Lafond, you have that $G \lor K_1 \lor K_1$ has subdivisions of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ as subgraphs.